# Can I use Front Matter in Jekyll Liquid Filters?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am attempting to create a related posts section. I have used loops and conditionals to achieve this before, but I wanted a more efficient and cleaner method. I used include variables to achieve a similar result, but for whatever reason if I attempt to use a post's front matter, I get an empty result. Example:

```
---
categories:
- Featured
---

{% assign featured-posts = site.posts | where: "categories", page.categories %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% assign featured-posts = site.posts | where: "categories", page.categories %}
```

`where` filter looks for a `string` in a `string` or in an `array`.
 Here `page.categories` is an `array` to look for in an `array`. This will return an empty array.

My shortest way to get related posts with at least one common category.

```
{% assign related-posts = "" | split: "" %}
{% for c in page.categories %}
  {% assign related-posts = related-posts | concat: site.categories[c] | uniq %}
{% endfor %}
```